# Eclipse IDE: Add/change default filetypes?

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-pdt

When I create a new file in Eclipse, there's a wide selection of different alternatives appearing in Eclipse.

However I am missing a couple of file which I need to open the "file create wizard" to create - JS files included.

How can I add my own file types as a default choice to appear in the "new files" menu?

Screenshot of the menu I am referring to:
[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Puuh - just when I had given up I accidentally found this:

> Try this: Right click on Eclipse's
>   toolbar and choose "Customize this
>   perspective" option. You will see a
>   dialog box, and on "Shortcuts" tab
>   choose "New" from "Submenus:"
>   droplist.
>
> Find "PHP" in the left pane and check
>   the checkbox next to it. It will
>   enable both "PHP File" and "PHP
>   Project" in "New" menu of your
>   perspective. You can do the same to
>   other file editors as well. (HTML,
>   CSS,....

http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.pdt/msg00228.html

Comment: On OSX it's Window -> 'Customize Perspective', then as above.

Comment: I have Luna on Windows 8.1 and it's Window -> Customize Perspective also.

Comment: "Eclipse's toolbar" is ambiguous.  Currently, "Mars", you have to right-click on the "Perspective toolbar"... or you can go Window menu --> Perspective --> Customize perspective

Answer (score 7):

Yes, from the Eclipse's toolbar, right click > Customize perspective... > Menu Visibility > File > New > check and uncheck file types.

Comment: This way is less clicking than Industrial's answer, since you see all the options in one long list.