# Frequently Used New File Type, Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

In Eclipse, is it possible to associate a chosen file type with the `New...` context menu when adding classes to a project, package, etc.? Or, am I stuck with the defaults that Eclipse provides? For instance, someone uses JavaScript `.js` classes, a lot, and would like to see them as an immediately available option.

Comment: In menu `Window - Preferences` in section `General - Keys` you could assign a shortkey for this kind of action.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse IDE: Add/change default filetypes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439798/eclipse-ide-add-change-default-filetypes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment yet, but this looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4439798/1879990)

In short, open the `Customize Perspective` window (from `Window` menu), select `Shortcuts`, then `New` in the `Submenus:` combo. You can then add e.g. `JavaScript` files to `Shortcut Categories:`

Comment: You're right. I've flagged the question as a duplicate (I don't know whether a moderator will pick it up as a duplicate or not). +1